# Maven Selenium Project - 'Cannot resolve symbol 'AssertionsForClassTypes' in IntelliJ

Tags: pom.xml, assertion, static-assert, assertthat

I am getting the following 2 errors in my Maven project:-

> '**Cannot resolve symbol 'AssertionsForClassTypes'**
> '**Cannot resolve method 'assertThat' in 'SearchTest'**

In the pom.xml file, the following dependency exists:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
    <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I also have the following in

```
<assertj.version>3.8.0</assertj.version>
```

This is what I have for import:-

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;
```

As suggested, I removed the  test  line from the dependency, but that did not solve the problem. what am I doing wrong? I would like to resolve the following errors:

> '**Cannot resolve symbol 'AssertionsForClassTypes'**
> '**Cannot resolve method 'assertThat' in 'SearchTest'**

Answer (score 0):

Updating the < assertj > version in the < properties > section of the pom.xml file resolved the issue. I also updated the < testng > version. After updating the versions, I resolved the Maven dependencies.
pom.xml file got updated with the following versions (as of Dec 27, 2022):-

```
 <testng.version>7.7.0</testng.version>
 <assertj.version>3.23.1</assertj.version>
```